# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list in a Kivy function

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Currently I have a function and this is getting values in a list called: list_buy. this list is working, and there are some "for" cycles that gather all the items and do an addition for getting one string result located in the "total" variable. The addition is working and the value is shown in a label Total_value. The problem is when one item from list_buy is removed I got the next error:

line 193, in remove_widget_instance
list_buy.remove(item_price)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

py.file

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    list_general= []
    list_price= []
    list_buy= []

    md= ObjectProperty(None) 
    def imprimir(self, list_general, list_price, list_buy):    
        print(list_general)
        for i in range(len(list_general)):
            #print(i)
            item_price= list_price[i]
            list_buy.append(item_price) 
            items= TwoLineListItem(text= list_general[i],secondary_text= "$"+list_price[i] + " Dollars" )
            items.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_widget_instance(items, self.md,list_buy,item_price))
         
            self.md.add_widget(items)       
            list_general.pop(i)
            list_price.pop(i)
            print(list_buy)
            #Check from here please.
            for i in range(len(list_buy)):
                list_buy[i]= float(list_buy[i])
            b = 0
            for i in list_buy:   
                b = b+i
                    
            total= str(b)+"0"
            self.ids.Total_value.text= total #This is working the total value is put in the label, but when is removed an item from the list_buy, I got the error

    def remove_widget_instance(self, instance, parent_widget, list_buy, item_price):
        parent_widget.remove_widget(instance)
        list_buy.remove(item_price) #I got the error here!
        print(list_buy)
```

main.file

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "Buy"
    md: container1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Productos Añadidos"
            font_size: 19
            #pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            #size: root.width, root.height+100
            #size_hint_y: .90
            size_hint: 1,0.3
    
        
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                #I need add here OneLineListItem
                id: container1
                #OneLineListItem: 
                #    id: item1
                #    text: "Awesome List #1"

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            size_hint: 1,0.3
            Label:
                text:"Total"
                #on_press: root.imprimir(root.list_torn)
            
            Label:
                id: Total_value
                text: "0.00"
                #on_text: root.total()
```

Comment: Don't add/remove items from a list while you're iterating over it.  Bad Things (tm) happen...

Comment: you shoud check `if item_price in list_buy: list_buy.remove(item_price)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are floating the items in list_buy without floating `item_price`

do this instead

```
def imprimir(self, list_general, list_price, list_buy):    
    print(list_general)
    list_buy = [float(x) for x in list_buy] #This line is to make sure that you float items in the list if the list is not empty before the for loop
    for i in range(len(list_general)):
        #print(i)
        item_price= list_price[i]
        item_price = float(item_price)
        list_buy.append(item_price) 
        items= TwoLineListItem(text= list_general[i],secondary_text= "$"+list_price[i] + " Dollars" )
        items.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_widget_instance(items, self.md,list_buy,item_price))
         
        self.md.add_widget(items)       
        list_general.pop(i)
        list_price.pop(i)
        print(list_buy)
        
    b = 0
    for i in list_buy:   
        b = b+i
                   
    total= str(b)+"0"
    self.ids.Total_value.text= total #This is working the total value is put in the label, but when is removed an item from the list_buy, I got the error
```

you need to be consistent when applying changes to a list and avoid a for loop within a for loop as much as possible. the error was pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks again, This code-line has helped me "item_price = float(item_price)" but "list_buy = [float(x) for x in list_buy]" is just taking the last value from the list_buy. It's not doing the addition. every time I sent a new value to the list just show the last value. and using this "for i in range(len(list_buy)):
                list_buy[i]= float(list_buy[i])" is doing the addition but when a value is removed is not doing the substraction, but when I add a new item to the list again. The value is shown in the Total_value again, I just need when the item is removed in the label change too.

Comment: I just figured out how to do it. I just posted the answer, thanks again. I think this project is finished now

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    list_general= []
    list_price= []
    list_buy= []

    md= ObjectProperty(None) #I need the MDList el id of container USar ObjectProperty()
    def imprimir(self, list_general, list_price, list_buy):    
        print(list_general)
        #list_buy= [float(x) for x in list_buy]
        for i in range(len(list_general)):
            #print(i)
            item_price= list_price[i]
            item_price= float(item_price)
            list_buy.append(item_price) 
            items= TwoLineListItem(text= list_general[i],secondary_text= "$"+list_price[i] + " Dollars" )
            items.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_widget_instance(items, self.md,list_buy,item_price))
            #self.root.ids.container1.add_widget(items)
            #md.add_widget(items) # It'S NOT WORKING HEREE!!!!!
            self.md.add_widget(items) # It'S Working now      
            list_general.pop(i)
            list_price.pop(i)
            print(list_buy)
            #Check from here please.
            for i in range(len(list_buy)):
                list_buy[i]= float(list_buy[i])
            b = 0
            for i in list_buy:   
                b = b+i

            #global total        
            total= str(b)+"0"
            self.ids.Total_value.text= total #This is working the total value is put in the label, but when is removed an item from the list_buy, I got the error

    def remove_widget_instance(self, instance, parent_widget, list_buy, item_price):
        parent_widget.remove_widget(instance)
        list_buy.remove(item_price) #I got the error here!
        for i in range(len(list_buy)):
                list_buy[i]= float(list_buy[i])
        b = 0
        for i in list_buy:   
            b = b+i

        #global total        
        total= str(b)+"0"
        self.ids.Total_value.text= total
        if self.ids.Total_value.text == "00":
            self.ids.Total_value.text= "0.00"

        print(list_buy)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).